# How to use mongodb change streams

Tags: mongodb, changestream

How do I use the change stream approach to reference a collection or number of collections for a user.

Scenario similar to Facebook where friends news shows on your feed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mongo.watch()`. It's available in mongo 4.0.

Read these docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo.watch/#Mongo.watch

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = new Mongo("mongodb://localhost:27017/demo?replicaSet=rs");
db = conn.getDB("demo");
collection = db.example;
const changeStreamCursor = collection.watch();
```

By using the parameterless `watch()` method, this change stream will signal every write to the example collection.

- https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/index.html#open-a-change-stream